# Do you have any other

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Can I use singular countable nouns after any other? And are the following sentences grammatical?

1- Do you have any other book?

2- Do you know any other doctor?

3- Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/any%20other), **any other** has two possible meanings.

The first meaning is used when we want to talk about a non-specific, single instance of the following noun. In this case, the noun is always singular, for example:

> On any other day, it wouldn't have been a problem.

The second meaning relates to other instances than those that have already been mentioned. It is conventional to make the noun plural:

> Do you have any other qualifications?

In your question, examples 1 and 2 relate to instances other than those already mentioned, and so a plural would sound more natural. Example 3 relates to a non-specific instance: any way of doing it would be fine, so a singular is OK.